# Why I don't get an exception when using operator [] with index out of range in std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl

Why when I use below code I don't get an out of range exception ?

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(12);
int t;
try {
    t = v[12];
} catch(std::exception  e){
    std::cout<<"error:"<<e.what()<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Also, Exceptions should always be thrown by value and catch by (preferrably, const) reference.

Comment: because the standard says so. If you want exceptions when out of bounds, use `std::vector::at()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By using `operator[]` you are essentially telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing. Trust me." If you access some element that is outside of the array it's your fault. You violated that trust; you didn't know what you were doing.

The alternative is to use the `at()` method. Here you are asking the compiler to do a sanity check on your accesses. If they're out of bounds you get an exception.

This sanity checking can be expensive, particularly if it is done in some deeply nested loop. There's no reason for those sanity checks if you *know* that the indices will always be in bounds. It's nice to have an interface that doesn't do those sanity checks.

The reason for making `operator[]` be the one that doesn't perform the checks is because this is exactly how `[]` works for raw arrays and pointers. There is no sanity check in C/C++ for accessing raw arrays/pointers. The burden is on you to do that checking if it is needed.

Comment: Quick note: while no exception occurs, when running as `Debug` for MSVC17, debug assertion failures will occur when trying to do this, explaining specifically, `Expression: vector subscript out of range`; also, ***this behavior will not occur with all types***, e.g. a regular `T[]` or an `std::byte`.

Answer (score 8):

`operator[]` doesn't throw an exception. Use the `at()` function for that behaviour.

Comment: In my program i use operator [] is way to fix it ?

Comment: @herzlshemuelian, The only reasonable way I see is to change each `operator[]` call to an `at` call. However, when debugging, I'm pretty sure some will let you choose to monitor out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: by choosing `operator[]` you've decided not to want out-of-bounds checking. If you now decide otherwise, you must pay the price for your change of mind.